# What is the difference between :method and :"method$##11" symbol?

Tags: ruby, symbols

Is `:"method$##11"` format used when special characters comes inside the symbol?

Comment: How did you get this String ?

Comment: @phtrivier..`"method$##11".to_sym`

Comment: `:"You can even put spaces in when you have quotation marks."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if your symbol name contains anything other than letters/numbers/underscores, you can quote it instead and it'll still be a symbol (otherwise you will get syntax errors when you don't use the quotes).

Also, using the same name quoted vs unquoted will be treated as the same symbol:

```
:test == :test2
# => false
:test == "test"
# => false
:test == :"test"
# => true
:test.object_id
# => 144328
:"test".object_id
# => 144328
```